# MessagSource does not return value

Tags: java, spring

I have spring project structure:

```
--resources
   - messages ( resource bundle )
      -messages.properties
      -messages_de.properties
```

messages_de properties file conatins:

```
test=hey!
```

And i want to retrieve data from it using:

```
    ResourceBundleMessageSource  source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasenames( "classpath:messages.messages");
    source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    source.getMessage("test", null, Locale.GERMAN);
```

however this piece of code returns "test" - e.g it did not find anything.

I have tried setting just

```
    source.setBasenames( "messages.messages");
```

yet nothing worked.

How can i configure messageSource to read the property and to actually find it?

Thanks for help

Comment: It's been a bit since I've had to configure this, but try `messages/messages`

Comment: i have tried, didnt work